# MySql JOIN on most recent start_date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with transactions (with date).  The other with a percentage and date the percentage it went into effect (assume 00:00:00).  The percentage remains in effect until a new percent goes into effect.  I need to join on the percentage that was in effect when the transaction happened.

```
transactions_table

event_date     amount
2011-01-01     230
2011-02-18     194
2011-03-22     56
2011-04-30     874

percent_table

effective     percent
2010-12-30    15
2011-03-05    25
2011-04-12    30
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
event_date     amount     percent
2011-01-01     230        15
2011-02-18     194        15
2011-03-22     56         25
2011-04-30     874        30
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT t.event_date, t.amount, p.percent 
FROM transactions_table AS t 
LEFT JOIN percent_table AS p ON t.event_date >= p.effective 
ORDER BY `t`.`event_date` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

That gives me, seemingly random percentages.  It seems to me like I need to get the greatest date >= p.effective, not just any random date >= p.effective.

I tried:

```
SELECT t.event_date, p.percent 
FROM bedic_sixsummits_transactions AS t 
LEFT JOIN bedic_sixsummits_percent AS p ON MAX(t.event_date >= p.effective) 
ORDER BY `t`.`event_date` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but MySQL just laughed at my feeble attempt.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.event_date, t.amount, p.percent
FROM bedic_sixsummits_transactions AS t
LEFT JOIN bedic_sixsummits_percent AS p
ON p.effective = 
   ( SELECT MAX( p2.effective ) FROM bedic_sixsummits_percent AS p2
     WHERE p2.effective <= t.event_date
   )
ORDER BY t.event_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Even more simpler and with no subquery:

```
SELECT event_date, amount, MAX(_percent) as _percent
FROM transactions_table
LEFT JOIN percent_table p1 ON event_date >= effective
GROUP BY event_date, amount
ORDER BY event_date;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8ca3/17/0

Note that it is possible because of the business model involved. If you wan't to retrieve other fields of the percent_table it won't be appropriate anymore :/

Comment: This worked perfectly as well.  In this query we just need to find the effective percent so it's appropriate.  Will this still work with different ORDER BY values (e.g., amount)?  Would this be faster than the subquery approach?

Comment: This approach only works if the percentage always increases over time. The query as it is currently written grabs the greatest percent value for all effective dates before and up to the event date, which isn't the same as grabbing the newest applicable value.

Comment: Thanks, I get it.  Thanks again Fred!